# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpUtility' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.0.1.0,

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

I am getting following error in my asp.net core 3.0 application

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpUtility' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

My application project file looks like follwoing

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>ubuntu.16.04-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64;win-x64;win10-x64;win10-x86;debian-x64;debian.8-x64;debian.9-x64;win81-x64;ubuntu.18.04-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />

  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What eventually i have did is removed the HttpUtility code and used some other workaround